# Extended DBContext Models in different projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have multiple applications that all share some tables (like Address, Company, etc), but have some additional tables that are product specific (let's say, Personnel). This is all in Database First strategy.

I would like to be able to share the classes generated by Entity Framework from a "Core" library (that has Address and Company), with products (that would have Personnel). This would be to avoid having duplicate classes defined.

I know I could obscure all of this through a Repository that holds multiple contexts, but that doesn't allow one critical thing (as far as I can tell), the automatic population of foreign keys from the Core schema (IE: populating and querying Personnel.Company). I could extend the class Personnel (either through the partial or with extension methods) to populate the Company from the CompanyID column, but this won't be persisted, meaning every access would be prohibitively expensive (unless I'm doing something wrong?)

So far I have read almost everything I can think of in respect to DBContext, including deriving the Product's DBContext from the Core DBContext (by altering the t4 template), and hoping it would magically set the value (sadly, it didn't). Really, I wish I could just point the T4 template at both EDMX's and let them magically work, but I don't think that is likely.